# Trouble with personalUnlockAccount,web3j

Tags: web3j, android, dao

I am creating android dapp for votings
I am trying to check if user's credentials are right,so i use object of PersonalUnlockAccount class and function accountUnlocked().So the problem is that when i call accountUnlocked() it gets me to the first activity and returns nothing
Here is the code

```
PersonalUnlockAccount personalUnlockAccount = null;
                personalUnlockAccount = web3.personalUnlockAccount(editTextAdress.
                        getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString()).sendAsync().get();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),true.,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (personalUnlockAccount.accountUnlocked()) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Rabotaet");
                ECKeyPair ecKeyPair = null;
                    ecKeyPair = Keys.createEcKeyPair();
                WalletUtils.generateWalletFile(editTextPassword.getText().toString(),ecKeyPair, new File(getCacheDir(),"wallet"), false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"UNLOCKED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG,"ne Rabotaet");                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PROBLEM",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

What could be done with this?

Comment: unlock is bad, if you want to test if the user has the private key, make him sign something for you and check if the signature is valid